# FosUserBundle redirect in a FilterUserResponseEvent

Tags: php, symfony, fosuserbundle, event-listener

I want to redirect my user after he clicks on the registration link but I'm stuck because there is no `setResponse` method in a `FilterUserResponseEvent`

**RegistrationListenner.php**

```
public static function getSubscribedEvents()
{
    return array(
        FOSUserEvents::REGISTRATION_CONFIRMED => 'onRegistrationConfirmed',
    );
}


public function onRegistrationConfirmed(FilterUserResponseEvent $event)
{
    $url = $this->router->generate('my_route', array('foo' => 'bar'));
    $response = new RedirectResponse($url);
    $event->setResponse(new RedirectResponse($url));
}
```

**services.xml**

```
    <service id="myapp.profile" class="MyApp\UserBundle\EventListener\ProfileListener">
        <tag name="kernel.event_subscriber"/>
        <argument type="service" id="router" />
    </service>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For this purpose there is the `GetResponseUserEvent` at the `REGISTRATION_CONFIRM` event, which asks for a response:

```
public static function getSubscribedEvents()
{
    return array(
            FOSUserEvents::REGISTRATION_CONFIRM => 'onRegistrationConfirm',
    );
}

public function onRegistrationConfirm(GetResponseUserEvent $event)
{
    $url = $this->router->generate('my_route', array('foo' => 'bar'));
    $response = new RedirectResponse($url);
    $event->setResponse(new RedirectResponse($url));
}
```

Comment: Oh didn't see that event. Thanks!

Comment: for me confirm not called (I think because confirmation work with email). help me

Comment: What? This event will be triggered, when the users clicks on the confirmation link in the email and just before confirming the account.

Comment: exactly, that's why it's not a correct answer when the website doesn't have to confirm users.

Comment: To have a registration link, confirm emails are mandatory. Without them, no links to click.

Answer (score 0):

in my version $event doesn't have setResponse() method but encapsulate the RedirectResponse object.

As object has already passed by reference you can use the setTargetUrl() to change the target url of the RedirectResponse.

You can do the redirection with this line :

```
$event->getResponse()->setTargetUrl("http://panel.it-strategy.fr")));
```